# Finish The Pattern #1

Tags: calculation-puzzle, pattern, number-sequence

Given a pattern: 12, 22, 35, 68, 15, 28, 31, $n$

Find the next item at $n$.

*Pattern/sequence explanation required*

Comment: I think this is a bit broad. You can answer any number, for example the solution of p(x)=(x-n)(x-12)(x-22)(x-35)...

Comment: Usually in puzzles like this, one expects a rule to generate the entire sequence, not one that describes only some of the values including missing value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partial answer:

> 60

because

> starting from the beginning, each even-indexed answer is (answer at index minus 1) * 2 - 2

Comment: Perfect answer!

Comment: Is there a rule for the odd-indexed values?